# quality standards problem

Tags: support, quality

What's the reason a perfectly normal post and question is not accepted?
I got the "This post does not meet our quality standards." message.

Can you help me regain the ability to post questions?

I already have tried many different titles and question contents.

Here's the question and text:

---

Title:

> bash validation with regex for just ascii letters

post:

> I'm doing this to validate a username:
>
> ```
> if [[ "$username" =~ ^[a-z][_a-z0-9]{2,17}$ ]]; then
> ```
>
> But actually, a username containing unicode characters like é, ç, à etc... is accepted.
>   What regex class should I use to limit strings to only ascii letters (a, b, c, d ... z) ?

Comment: You have not lost the ability, you just need to improve the question.

Comment: no, my question is perfect. And I tried many different titles and question contents. I just can't post anymore.

Comment: The filter seems to think otherwise. Show us the question you want to ask and we can have a look.

Comment: You should not get that error message if you "can't post anymore".

Comment: Obviously, if you receive this error, it is not "a perfectly fine and normal post". Also, including what you tried to post would help us help you help us all.

Comment: I posted the question that doesn't get accepted. This is only one of the many titles and content I tried.

Comment: Have you tried capital letters in the title?

Comment: Tadaaa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731455/bash-validation-with-regex-for-just-ascii-letters @psubsee2003

Comment: Ok, it works when capitalizing the title. The message should be more explicit. "Doesn't meet our quality standards". How about "Your title should start with a capital letter" ?

Comment: That is by design @JohnSmithOptional. See the possible duplicate.

Comment: There already an SO user with the name "John Smith".  He posts remarkably poor questions at a high rate, basic typing skills are but one of his challenges.  Just plain lazy too, can't be bothered to make his questions readable, lifting his pinky finger is too much trouble.  The kind of behavior that the machine tries to filter.  It of course doesn't try to help him being a little less lazy, that entirely defeats the purpose.  You might want to avoid using that same name.

Answer (score 4):

Try correctly capitalizing both title and the body. You have at least 3 issues I see:

- ASCII is an acronym so should be all caps
- Bash is a proper noun as well as the first word in the sentence.
- Unicode is a proper noun as well.

I know it seems like school, but grammar counts in professional writing.  Good quality questions are usually written professionally in addition to being good questions.

Comment: "Try putting at least 1 capital letter in the title." I think what you tried to say is "Try correctly capitalizing words in the title".

Comment: I just copied by comment, but that is probably a better choice of words, thanks.